# What's the name of hair left in your razor?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the single word for the tiny pieces of hair left in your razor after you shave?

Comment: I use the word "hair".

Comment: Hope you're not thinking of hair *[clippings](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clipping)* and/or *trimmings*, which are the ends of hair that has been cut off because they do not refer to hair found in razors.

Comment: *Detrius* comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I've never heard the word used in practice, several online slang dictionaries list [**snoodge**](http://www.diclib.com/cgi-bin/d1.cgi?l=en&base=amslang&page=showid&id=9297#.UuhLn2TTlcw) with this meaning:

> The substance (consisting of compressed hair shavings, skin, shave cream, blood, and other facial detritus) that collects between the blades of a multi-blade razor, diminishing its effectiveness.
>   *Next razor I buy, I'm getting the kind with the built-in snoodge ejector, so it won't get clogged up and thrown away so quickly.*

This sounds to me more like a [sniglet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sniglet) than a slang word in actual use. I would use Gnawme's suggestion of *stubble* instead if you prefer clarity to cleverness.

Comment: ‘Snoodge’ is used (I've heard it referred to as ‘snudge’ as well), but it means something slightly different. I understand the question here to be about stray hairs that get stuck in the razor, whereas snoodge is more of a gooey substance that clogs up the razor—individual hairs are not identifiable in snoodge, it's just basically goo.

Comment: Ah, interesting. The sources I found did not seem particularly reliable (and were obviously just copying one another) so I suspected that it was not a real word in actual use. It's quite possible that it's the word that the OP vaguely remembers out of the past, though.

Comment: Bradd -- my memory being what it is (isn't), I  believe "snooge" must've been the word I was trying to remember. It certainly wasn't a common word like "stubble" or "hair", but still a simple, one-syllable word. Could be a sniglet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9):

It's called *stubble* on your face, and it's still called *stubble* [in your razor](http://www.askmen.com/fashion/fashiontip_400/438_make-your-shaving-blades-last-longer.html).

Comment: I don't know why my stupid answer got voted up and why he didn't accept your answer, I almost fear the reason might be me i.e on witnessing my answer,he thought he won't get competent answers here .

Comment: I AM new, folks. Don't mean to offend, but I haven't seen an answer to "upvote/accept". Thanks for the efforts.

Comment: Not a problem. Are you looking for a word that you might have heard in the past, and none of the answers posted thus far are that word?

Comment: Correct. Years ago. And I didn't write it down . . .

Comment: Stubble is the short stubs barely sticking out on your face. That does not describe at all the pieces of whiskers hanging on the razor on in the sink.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to it as residual hair .

Comment: Thanks, but I remember it as a single word that specifically meant what I indicated.

Comment: I thought so ...but this won't be incorrect